# Unexpected output while using 'neuralnet' in R

Tags: r, neural-network

I'm using the `neuralnet` package of `R` for the prediction of hand written digits. [MNIST database](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) is being used for training and testing of this algorithm. Here is the `R` code I used:

```
# Importing the data into R
path <- "path_to_data_folder/MNIST_database_of_handwritten_digits/"  # Data can be downloaded from: http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/
to.read = file(paste0(path, "train-images-idx3-ubyte"), "rb")
to.read_Label = file(paste0(path, "train-labels-idx1-ubyte"), "rb")
magicNumber <- readBin(to.read, integer(), n=1, endian="big")
magicNumber_Label <- readBin(to.read_Label, integer(), n=1, endian="big")
numberOfImages <- readBin(to.read, integer(), n=1, endian="big")
numberOfImages_Label <- readBin(to.read_Label, integer(), n=1, endian="big")
rowPixels <- readBin(to.read, integer(), n=1, endian="big")
columnPixels <- readBin(to.read, integer(), n=1, endian="big")

# image(1:rowPixels, 1:columnPixels, matrix(readBin(to.read, integer(), n=(rowPixels*columnPixels), size=1, endian="big"), rowPixels, columnPixels)[,columnPixels:1], col=gray((0:255)/255))

trainDigits <- NULL
trainDigits <- vector(mode="list", length=numberOfImages)
for(i in 1:numberOfImages)
  trainDigits[[i]] <- as.vector(matrix(readBin(to.read, integer(), n=(rowPixels*columnPixels), size=1, endian="big"), rowPixels, columnPixels)[,columnPixels:1])

trainDigits <- t(data.frame(trainDigits))  # Takes a minute
trainDigits <- data.frame(trainDigits, row.names=NULL)

# i <- 1  # Specify the image number to visualize the image
# image(1:rowPixels, 1:columnPixels, matrix(trainDigits[i,], rowPixels, columnPixels), col=gray((0:255)/255))

trainDigits_Label <- NULL
for(i in 1:numberOfImages_Label)
  trainDigits_Label <- c(trainDigits_Label, readBin(to.read_Label, integer(), n=1, size=1, endian="big"))

# appending the labels to the training data
trainDigits <- cbind(trainDigits, trainDigits_Label)

#################### Modelling ####################

library(neuralnet)
# Considering only 500 rows for training due to time and memory constraints
myNnet <- neuralnet(formula = as.formula(paste0("trainDigits_Label ~ ", paste0("X",1:(ncol(trainDigits)-1), collapse="+"))),
                                data = trainDigits[1:500,], hidden = 10, algorithm='rprop+', learningrate=0.01)

#################### Test Data ####################

to.read_test = file(paste0(path, "t10k-images-idx3-ubyte"), "rb")
to.read_Label_test = file(paste0(path, "t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte"), "rb")
magicNumber <- readBin(to.read_test, integer(), n=1, endian="big")
magicNumber_Label <- readBin(to.read_Label_test, integer(), n=1, endian="big")
numberOfImages_test <- readBin(to.read_test, integer(), n=1, endian="big")
numberOfImages_Label_test <- readBin(to.read_Label_test, integer(), n=1, endian="big")
rowPixels <- readBin(to.read_test, integer(), n=1, endian="big")
columnPixels <- readBin(to.read_test, integer(), n=1, endian="big")

testDigits <- NULL
testDigits <- vector(mode="list", length=numberOfImages_test)
for(i in 1:numberOfImages_test)
  testDigits[[i]] <- as.vector(matrix(readBin(to.read_test, integer(), n=(rowPixels*columnPixels), size=1, endian="big"), rowPixels, columnPixels)[,columnPixels:1])

testDigits <- t(data.frame(testDigits))  # Takes a minute
testDigits <- data.frame(testDigits, row.names=NULL)

testDigits_Label <- NULL
for(i in 1:numberOfImages_Label_test)
  testDigits_Label <- c(testDigits_Label, readBin(to.read_Label_test, integer(), n=1, size=1, endian="big"))

#################### 'neuralnet' Predictions ####################

predictOut <- compute(myNnet, testDigits)
table(round(predictOut$net.result), testDigits_Label)

#################### Random Forest ####################
# Cross-validating NN results with Random Forest

library(randomForest)
myRF <- randomForest(x=trainDigits[,-ncol(trainDigits)], y=as.factor(trainDigits_Label), ntree=100)

predRF <- predict(myRF, newdata=testDigits)
table(predRF, testDigits_Label)  # Confusion Matrix
sum(diag(table(predRF, testDigits_Label)))/sum(table(predRF, testDigits_Label))  # % of correct predictions
```

There are 60,000 training images (28*28 pixel images) and the digits 0 to 9 are distributed (almost) equally among the entire dataset. Unlike in the 'modelling' part above where I used only 500 images, I used the entire training dataset to train a `myNnet` model (28*28=784 inputs and 10 outputs) and then predicted the output of the 10,000 images in the test dataset. (I used only 10 neurons in the hidden layer due to memory constraints.)

The results I obtained with the prediction are weird: the output was kind of a Gaussian distribution where 4 was predicted most of the time and the predictions towards 0 or 9 from 4 decreased (kind of) exponentially. You can see the confusion matrix below (I rounded off the outputs since they were not integers):

```
> table(round(predictOut$net.result), testDigits_Label)
    testDigits_Label
       0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
  -2   1   1   4   1   1   3   0   4   1   2
  -1   8  17  12   9   7   8   8  12   7  10
  0   38  50  44  45  35  28  36  40  30  39
  1   77 105  86  80  71  69  68  75  67  77
  2  116 163 126 129 101  97 111 101  99 117
  3  159 205 196 174 142 140 153 159 168 130
  4  216 223 212 183 178 170 177 169 181 196
  5  159 188 150 183 183 157 174 176 172 155
  6  119 111 129 125 143 124 144 147 129 149
  7   59  53  52  60  74  52  51  91  76  77
  8   22  14  18  14  32  36  28  38  35  41
  9    6   5   3   7  15   8   8  16   9  16
```

I thought there must be something wrong my approach, so I tried prediction using the `randomForest` package of `R`. But, `randomForest` worked fine giving an accuracy of more than 95%. Here is the confusion matrix of `randomForest` predictions:

```
> table(predRF, testDigits_Label)
      testDigits_Label
predRF    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
     0  967    0    6    1    1    7   11    2    5    5
     1    0 1123    0    0    0    1    3    7    0    5
     2    1    2  974    9    3    1    3   25    4    2
     3    0    3    5  963    0   21    0    0    9   10
     4    0    0   12    0  940    1    4    2    7   15
     5    4    0    2   16    0  832    6    0   11    4
     6    6    5    5    0    7   11  929    0    3    2
     7    1    1   14    7    2    2    0  979    4    6
     8    1    1   12    7    5   11    2    1  917   10
     9    0    0    2    7   24    5    0   12   14  950
```

- **Question 1:** So, can anyone please explain me why is `neuralnet` having this strange behaviour with this dataset? (BTW, `neuralnet` was working fine with `iris` dataset when I checked).

  - **EDIT:** *I think I understood the reason for the Gaussian kind of distribution in the output when `neuralnet` is used. There is only one output node (or is it neuron?) instead of a node for each output class (which is 10 classes here) when `neuralnet` is used. So, while calculating the **delta** for back-propagation, the algorithm computes the difference of the 'expected output' to 'calculated output', which on aggregating for all the instances will be least for those instances where the output is either 4 or 5.[image: Error] So, the weights will be adjusted during back-propagation in such way that the output error is minimized. This 'might' be the reason for the Gaussian kind of output given by `neuralnet`.*
- **Question 2:** And also I want to know how to rectify this behaviour of `neuralnet` and get predictions on par with the `randomForest` results.

Comment: see [this example](http://www.parallelr.com/r-dnn-parallel-acceleration/) of native R for DNN with MNIST dataset.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some preliminary advice, you can load your data in like this a little more efficiently:

```
# Read in data.
trainDigits <- replicate(numberOfImages,c(matrix(readBin(to.read, integer(), n=(rowPixels*columnPixels), size=1, endian="big"),rowPixels,columnPixels)[,columnPixels:1]))
trainDigits <- data.frame(t(trainDigits),row.names=NULL)
trainDigits_Label<-replicate(numberOfImages,readBin(to.read_Label, integer(), n=1, size=1, endian="big"))
```

Your first problem is that you have not specified a multiclass prediction to `neuralnet`. What you were doing was predicting a real number, from 0 to 9. That is why there was only one output, instead of 10 predictions.

If you look in `?neuralnet` there is an example of a multiclass prediction; you must put each class in a separate variable, and put it on the left side of the `formula`. Other packages, like `nnet`, will automatically detect a `factor` and do this for you. You can use the `classInd` function to split a factor into multiple variables:

```
# appending the labels to the training data
output <- class.ind(trainDigits_Label)
colnames(output)<-paste0('out.',colnames(output))
output.names<-colnames(output)
input.names<-colnames(trainDigits)
trainDigits<-cbind(output,trainDigits)
```

Now you can paste together a formula:

```
# Considering only 500 rows
trainsize=500
# neuralnet:::varify.variables (sic) does not pass "data" when calling "terms".
# If it did, you wouldn't have to construct the formula like this.
library(neuralnet)
myNnet <- neuralnet(formula = paste(paste(output.names,collapse='+'),'~',
                              paste(input.names,collapse='+')),
                    data = trainDigits[1:trainsize,],
                    hidden = 10, 
                    algorithm='rprop+', 
                    learningrate=0.01,
                    rep=1)
```

The correction still doesn't make the neural network perform well. To get an idea of how bad the neural network is doing look at how it performs on *the training data*. It should be pretty good, because it has seen all this data before:

```
# Accuracy on training data
res<-compute(myNnet,trainDigits[1:trainsize,input.names])
picks<-(0:9)[apply(res$net.result,1,which.max)]
prop.table(table(trainDigits_Label[1:trainsize] == picks))
# FALSE  TRUE 
# 0.376 0.624
```

An accuracy of 62% is terrible on training data. As you might expect, it performs at barely above random on the rest of the data:

```
# Accuracy on test data
res<-compute(myNnet,trainDigits[(trainsize+1):60000,input.names])
picks<-(0:9)[apply(res$net.result,1,which.max)]
prop.table(table(trainDigits_Label[(trainsize+1):60000] == picks))
# FALSE         TRUE 
# 0.8612268908 0.1387731092 
# 14% accuracy
```

Random forest does amazingly well with the exact same data. There is a good reason why it has become so popular lately.

```
trainsize=500
library(randomForest)
myRF <- randomForest(trainDigits_Label~.,
                     data=data.frame(trainDigits_Label=as.factor(trainDigits_Label),
                                     trainDigits[input.names])[1:trainsize,],
                     ntree=100)

# Train
p <- as.numeric(as.character(predict(myRF)))
prop.table(table(trainDigits_Label[1:trainsize]==p))
# Accuracy: 79%    

# Test
p <- as.numeric(as.character(predict(myRF,trainDigits[(trainsize+1):60000,])))
prop.table(table(trainDigits_Label[(trainsize+1):60000]==p))
# Accuracy: 76%
```

So, for your second question, my counter question is: why would you expect the neural network to do as well as random forest? They might have some vague structural similarities, but the fitting process is quite different. I guess you could pore over the nodes in the neural network and compare them to the most important variables in the random forest model. But, at this point, it is more of a statistical question than a programming one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insights on how to use `neuralnet` for multi-class classification. Yes, it is very interesting to see how RF being so simple algorithm is able to perform so well on this task. Regarding your counter question, I see neural networks to be an algorithm so powerful that it can learn to recognize any kind of patterns that are hardly seen by other ML algorithms. Even in case of simple patterns, I expected that neural networks would adjust its weights in such a way that it would mimic the behaviour other algorithms which would detect those patterns.

Comment: I agree that neural networks are *flexible*, and this may allow them to recognize patterns unseen by other machines. But that does not mean they are more *powerful*; the flexibility makes them harder to fit, easier for them to get trapped in local minima, and more likely to overfit to training data (as seen in this case).

Answer (score 3):

I want to thank all previous authors in this discussion, because it is the most informative source on the *neuralnet* package usage over the net! This discussion was VERY helpful for me to study *neuralnet* R package.

**On Question 2**: it is possible to use *neuralnet* to predict digit Labels with **better accuracy** using these hints:

- use more neurons. 10 neurons in hidden layer is not enough. At least 30 neurons should be used.
- normalize and center inputs before training. Read Max Kuhn's "[Applied Predictive Modeling](http://www.springer.com/statistics/life+sciences,+medicine+%26+health/book/978-1-4614-6848-6)", chapter 3.
- *learningrate* parameter is used only for "backprop" algorithm. For other algorithms (rprop+, sag, slr,...) use *learningrate.limit* and *learningrate.factor* parameters.
- use more training data.

With 30 neurons NN will give:

> ```
> [1] "NN to predict Labels."  
> [1] "Confusion matrix for training set:"
>         Expected   
> Predicted   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
>         0  96   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
>         1   1 116   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
>         2   0   0  99   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
>         3   0   0   0  93   0   0   0   0   0   0
>         4   0   0   0   0 104   1   0   0   0   0
>         5   0   0   0   0   1  91   0   0   0   0
>         6   0   0   0   0   0   0  94   0   0   0
>         7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 117   0   0
>         8   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  87   0
>         9   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 100
> [1] "Model accuracy on training set is 99.7%"
>
> [1] "Confusion matrix for test set:"
>          Expected 
> Predicted   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
>         0 337 380 257 160  87  85  67  25  45  30
>         1 134 169  97  77  60  64  70  32  41  16
>         2 121 179 112 109  59  79  69  31  55  27
>         3 119 136 138 114  99 102  96  67  66  55
>         4  87 102  91 135 106 102 104  86  87  54
>         5  84  75  95 114 114  91 142 104  82  66
>         6  48  41  80  98 106 116 144 138 104  92
>         7  22  28  55  82 103  78 100 146 104 124
>         8  16   9  42  56  80  60  65 123  93 125
>         9  12  16  65  65 168 115 101 276 297 420 
> [1] "Model accuracy on test set is 17.32%"
> ```
>
> The test results are far from good, but the confusion matrix has diagonal shape what means that the model is working in right direction. This model accuracy can be improoved by playing with training set size and threshold. I've got accuracy about 30%. But this model is limited and the best results can be obtained with the model which would predict Label Class instead of Label. I was able to get accuracy about 80% from shuch model with *neuralnet* packge.

With 30 neurons and 1000 training size this NN gives:

> ```
> [1] "NN to predict Label Classes." 
> [1] "Confusion matrix for training set:"
>         Expected 
> Predicted   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
>         0  95   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
>         1   0 113   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
>         2   0   0  98   0   0   2   0   1   0   0
>         3   1   2   0  93   1   0   0   1   0   0
>         4   0   0   0   0 104   0   0   0   0   1
>         5   1   1   0   0   0  90   0   1   0   0
>         6   0   0   0   0   0   0  93   0   0   0
>         7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 112   0   0
>         8   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  86   0
>         9   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1  98 
> [1] "Model accuracy on training set is 98.2%" 
> [1] "Confusion matrix for test set:"
>         Expected 
> Predicted    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
>         0  791    0   32   28   11   62   12   25   20   22
>         1    1 1050   13    4   10   10    2   13   31   35
>         2   24    2  580   59    8   13   39   73   26   24
>         3   42   14  105  607   79  112   74   68  106  124
>         4   10   12   40   28  495   62   59   20   83   83
>         5   39   31   25  126   35  444   71    6   54   22
>         6   13    3   45    7   22   15  554    3   18   13
>         7    4    4   31   11   37   10    7  732   11   66
>         8   21    7   92   79   51   96   50   19  518   21
>         9   35   12   69   61  234   68   90   69  107  599 
> [1] "Model accuracy on test set is 63.7%"
> ```

```
#################### Importing the data into R ##########
#path <- "path_to_data_folder/MNIST_database_of_handwritten_digits/"  # Data can be downloaded from: http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/
path <- "../MNIST_DATA/UNZIP/"
to.read = file(paste0(path, "train-images.idx3-ubyte"), "rb")
to.read_Label = file(paste0(path, "train-labels.idx1-ubyte"), "rb")
magicNumber <- readBin(to.read, integer(), n=1, endian="big")
magicNumber_Label <- readBin(to.read_Label, integer(), n=1, endian="big")
numberOfImages <- readBin(to.read, integer(), n=1, endian="big")
numberOfImages_Label <- readBin(to.read_Label, integer(), n=1, endian="big")
rowPixels <- readBin(to.read, integer(), n=1, endian="big")
columnPixels <- readBin(to.read, integer(), n=1, endian="big")

trainDigits <- NULL

#Trick #1: read unsigned data
trainDigits <- replicate(numberOfImages,c(matrix(readBin(to.read, integer(), n=(rowPixels*columnPixels), 
                                                         size=1, endian="big", signed=F),
                                                 rowPixels,columnPixels)[,columnPixels:1]))
trainDigits <- data.frame(t(trainDigits),row.names=NULL)
trainDigits_Label<-replicate(numberOfImages,readBin(to.read_Label, integer(), n=1, size=1, endian="big", signed=F))
close(to.read)
close(to.read_Label)

#################### Test Data ####################

to.read_test = file(paste0(path, "t10k-images.idx3-ubyte"), "rb")
to.read_Label_test = file(paste0(path, "t10k-labels.idx1-ubyte"), "rb")
magicNumber <- readBin(to.read_test, integer(), n=1, endian="big")
magicNumber_Label <- readBin(to.read_Label_test, integer(), n=1, endian="big")
numberOfImages_test <- readBin(to.read_test, integer(), n=1, endian="big")
numberOfImages_Label_test <- readBin(to.read_Label_test, integer(), n=1, endian="big")
rowPixels <- readBin(to.read_test, integer(), n=1, endian="big")
columnPixels <- readBin(to.read_test, integer(), n=1, endian="big")

#read unsigned data 
testDigits <- replicate(numberOfImages_test,c(matrix(readBin(to.read, integer(), n=(rowPixels*columnPixels), 
                                                             size=1, endian="big", signed=F),
                                                     rowPixels,columnPixels)[,columnPixels:1]))
testDigits <- data.frame(t(testDigits),row.names=NULL)
testDigits_Label<-replicate(numberOfImages_test,readBin(to.read_Label_test, integer(), n=1, size=1, endian="big", signed=F))
close(to.read_test)
close(to.read_Label_test)

#################### Modelling ####################

library(neuralnet)

#add Label data to training data.frame
trainData <- cbind(trainDigits_Label, trainDigits)
names(trainData)[1] <- "Label"

#Reduce training data for speedup
trainSample <- 1000 #use more then 500 rows to get better model accuracy (slow!)
trainData <- trainData[1:trainSample,]
myThreshold <- trainSample/5000 #use smaller threshold to get better model accuracy (slow!)

#Trick #2: normalize and center pixel data before trainig and testing
normFactor <- max(trainData) #=255
trainData[,-1] <- trainData[,-1]/normFactor #normalize inputs
centerFactor <- mean(as.matrix(trainData[,-1])) #0.5 mean по столбцу? 
trainData[,-1] <- trainData[,-1]- centerFactor #center inputs
testDigits <- testDigits/normFactor - centerFactor

#Trick #3: use more neurons in the hidden layer to rise the model accuracy
nHidden=30

#train model which predicts Labels
myFormula <- as.formula(paste0("Label ~ ", paste0("X",1:(ncol(trainDigits)), collapse="+")))
myNnet <- neuralnet(formula = myFormula, data = trainData, hidden = c(nHidden), 
                    algorithm='rprop+', #learningrate=0.01,
                    learningrate.limit=list(min=c(1e-10), max=c(0.01)), #default values min/max = 1e-10/0.1
                    learningrate.factor=list(minus=c(0.5), plus=c(1.2)), #default values minus/plus = 0.5/1.2
                    err.fct="sse", #Using "sum square errors" function for Error
                    act.fct="tanh",#Using tangent hyperbolicus activation smoothing function 
                    threshold=myThreshold,
                    lifesign="full", lifesign.step=500,
                    stepmax=3e05)

#Trick #4: get rid of negative predictions. consider them to be equal to zero. 
#The same with too big predictions (>9)
myNnet$net.result[[1]][myNnet$net.result[[1]]<0]<-0
myNnet$net.result[[1]][myNnet$net.result[[1]]>9]<-9

#################### 'neuralnet' Predictions ####################

predictOut <- compute(myNnet, testDigits)
predictOut$net.result[predictOut$net.result<0] <- 0
predictOut$net.result[predictOut$net.result>9] <- 9

#################### Result analysis ####################

#Model accuracy on training data
confTrain <- table(Predicted=round(myNnet$net.result[[1]]), Expected=(trainData[,"Label"]))
print("NN to predict Labels.")
print("Confusion matrix for training set:")
print (confTrain)
print(paste0("Model accuracy on training set is ", round(sum(diag(confTrain))/sum(confTrain)*100,4), "%"))

#Model accuracy on test data
confTest <- table(Predicted=round(predictOut$net.result), Expected=testDigits_Label)
print("Confusion matrix for test set:")
print (confTest)
print(paste0("Model accuracy on test set is ", round(sum(diag(confTest))/sum(confTest)*100,4), "%"))



#########################################################################################
#Trick #5: Predict digit Class instead of predicting digit Label
#Replace each Label with a vector of 10 bits "Label classes"
library (nnet)

# appending the Label classes to the training data
output <- class.ind(trainData[,"Label"])
colnames(output)<-paste0('out.',colnames(output))
output.names<-colnames(output)
input.names<-colnames(trainData[,-1])
trainData <-cbind(output,trainData)

#train model which predicts Label classes
myFormula <- as.formula(paste0(paste0(output.names,collapse='+')," ~ ", 
                               paste0(input.names, collapse="+")))
myNnetClass <- neuralnet(formula = myFormula, data = trainData, hidden = c(nHidden), 
                  algorithm='sag', #learningrate=0.01,
                  learningrate.limit=list(min=c(1e-10), max=c(0.01)), #default values min/max = 1e-10/0.1
                  learningrate.factor=list(minus=c(0.5), plus=c(1.2)), #default values minus/plus = 0.5/1.2
                  err.fct="sse", #Using "sum square errors" function for Error
                  act.fct="tanh",#Using tangent hyperbolicus activation smoothing function 
                  threshold=myThreshold, 
                  lifesign="full", lifesign.step=500,
                  stepmax=3e05)


# Convert  binary output to categorical output (labels)
nnres=myNnetClass$net.result[[1]]
myNnetClass$net.result[[1]] <- (0:9)[apply(myNnetClass$net.result[[1]],1,which.max)]


#################### 'neuralnet' Predictions ####################

predictOutClass <- compute(myNnetClass, testDigits)
colnames(predictOutClass$net.result) <- paste0("Cl", 0:9)
predictedLabel <- (0:9)[apply(predictOutClass$net.result, 1, which.max)]

#################### Result analysis ####################

#Model accuracy on training data
confTrain <- table(Predicted=myNnetClass$net.result[[1]], Expected=trainData[,"Label"])
print("NN to predict Label Classes.")
print("Confusion matrix for training set:")
print (confTrain)
print(paste0("Model accuracy on training set is ", round(sum(diag(confTrain))/sum(confTrain)*100,4), "%"))

#Model accuracy on test data
confTest <- table(Predicted=predictedLabel, Expected=testDigits_Label)
print("Confusion matrix for test set:")
print (confTest)
print(paste0("Model accuracy on test set is ", round(sum(diag(confTest))/sum(confTest)*100,4), "%"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for these insights ASH. I currently moved on from this problem, but would like to try out your suggestions.