# R Package Deepnet: Training and Testing the MNIST dataset

Tags: r, neural-network, deep-learning, rbm

I am trying to train the MNIST dataset using **deepenet** package's *dbn.dnn.train* function. The task is a classification one.
I am using the following command

```
dbn.deepnet <- dbn.dnn.train(train.image.data,train.image.labels,hidden=c(5,5))
```

The problems I am facing are:

1) The labels should be factor type vector. But when i input the labels as factor the function gives an error that "y should be a matrix or vector". So, I am using labels as numeric. How to proceed for a classification task

2) What it the function to make the predictions for dbn.dnn.train. I am using nn.predict but the documentation mentions that the input should be neural network trained by function nn.train (dbn.dnn.train is not mentioned).
The output is 0.9986 for all records

```
nn.predict(dbn.deepnet,train.image.data)
```

Comment: Maybe you should try **neuralnet** package instead?  Please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827195/unexpected-output-while-using-neuralnet-in-r  Hope this may help.

Comment: Thanks! But I am trying to implement deep learning specifically deep belief nets which is not provided by the package neuralnet

Comment: An example of training MNIST w/ `deepnet` can be found in [here](http://www.parallelr.com/r-with-parallel-computing/) and speedup info in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32239487/why-r-deepnet-slow-how-can-i-speed-up/39554401#39554401).

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if you are still working on it, or if you've found the solution but :
 1/ try this : train.image.labels <- data.matrix(train.image.labels)

2/ i use nn.predict,  even if the neural network is trained by dbn.dnn.train.

Answer (score 1):

As you know the input values for neural network better to be between 0 and 1. In "deepnet" package, unlike the `nn.train` function, for `dbn.dnn.train` you need to normalize the input yourself. Here is the complete code to load, train, and test.

```
#loading MNIST
setwd("path/to/MNIST/")
mnist <- load.mnist(".")
# the function to normalize the input values
normalize <- function(x) {
  return (x/255)
}
# standardization
train_x_n <-  apply(mnist$train$x, c(1,2),FUN = normalize)
test_x_n <- apply(mnist$test$x, c(1,2),FUN = normalize)
#training and prediction
dnn <- dbn.dnn.train(train_x_n, mnist$train$yy, hidden = c(100, 70, 80), numepochs = 3, cd = 3)
err.dnn <- nn.test(dnn, test_x_n, mnist$test$yy)
dnn_predict <- nn.predict(dnn, test_x_n)
# test the outputs
print(err.dnn)
print(dnn_predict[1,])
print(mnist$test$y[1])
```

Outout:

```
> err.dnn
[1] 0.0829
> dnn_predict[1,]
[1] 7.549055e-04 1.111647e-03 1.946491e-03 7.417489e-03 3.221340e-04 7.306264e-04 4.088365e-05 9.944441e-01 8.953903e-05
[10] 9.085863e-03
> mnist$test$y[1]
[1] 7
```