# Why R deepnet slow? How can I speed up?

Tags: r, performance

Recently, I use the "deepnet" to train the MNIST.

My code is :

```
testMNIST <- function(){

    mnist <- load.mnist("./mnist/")
    cat ("Load MNIST data succeed!", "\n")

    train_x <- mnist$train$x
    train_y <- mnist$train$y
    train_y_mat <- mnist$train$yy

    test_x <- mnist$test$x
    test_y <- mnist$test$y
    test_y_mat <- mnist$test$yy

    dnn <- dbn.dnn.train(train_x, train_y, hidden = c(1000, 500, 200), learningrate = 0.01, numepochs = 100)

    err_rate <- nn.test(dnn, test_x, test_y)
    cat ("The Error rate of training DBN with label vector:", "\n")
    print (err_rate)
}
```

I run the code on a Linux service (24GB memory, 1T hard disc), but the speed is so slowly. It just trained one layer for 12 hours.
So, how can I improve the performance?
And for labels like MNIST data, when training, vector label or matrix label, which is better?

Comment: Hi. Are there any else good R packages about "deep learning"?

Comment: There are two problems with this code. First) you need to use `mnist$train$yy` to train the DNN. Second) without standardization you will get erroneous results because `dnn.train` does not standardize the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**, `deepnet` is written by R itself so it's a little slow. The most time-consuming function in `deepnet` is matrix multiplications. Therefore, adding parallel BLAS in the backend would be very useful, such as [Intel MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl), [OpenBLAS](http://www.openblas.net/) and even [NVIDIA cuBLAS](https://developer.nvidia.com/cublas).

One example in the [R with Parallel Computing with User Perspectives blog](http://www.parallelr.com/r-with-parallel-computing/) of implicit parallel mode parts, the OpenBLAS can **2.5X** speedup compared w/ native R + deepnet.

```
#install.packages("data.table")
#install.packages("deepnet")

library(data.table)
library(deepnet)

# download MNIST dataset in below links
# https://h2o-public-test-data.s3.amazonaws.com/bigdata/laptop/mnist/train.csv.gz
# https://h2o-public-test-data.s3.amazonaws.com/bigdata/laptop/mnist/test.csv.gz
mnist.train <- as.matrix(fread("./train.csv", header=F))
mnist.test  <- as.matrix(fread("./test.csv", header=F))

# V785 is the label
x <- mnist.train[, 1:784]/255
y <- model.matrix(~as.factor(mnist.train[, 785])-1)

system.time(
nn <- dbn.dnn.train(x,y,
                    hidden=c(64),
                    #hidden=c(500,500,250,125),
                    output="softmax",
                    batchsize=128, 
                    numepochs=100, 
                    learningrate = 0.1)
)
```

And the results as below *2115 sec* .vs. *867 sec*.

```
> R CMD BATCH deepnet_mnist.R
> cat deepnet_mnist.Rout
deep nn has been trained.
 user system elapsed 
 2110.710 2.311 2115.042

> env LD_PRELOAD=/.../tools/OpenBLAS/lib/libopenblas.so R CMD BATCH deepnet_mnist.R
> cat deepnet_mnist.Rout
deep nn has been trained.
 user system elapsed 
 2197.394 10496.190 867.748
```

**Secondly**, [H2O](http://www.h2o.ai) and [MXNET](http://mxnet.io/) will be faster for deep learning.

**Finally**, please note your network of `hidden = c(1000, 500, 200)` is really huge and it will be VERY slow even with multicores :(